# How do I display the Observable data I am getting from my api call using Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I am very new to angular and I'm trying to get a simple App to display a list of products. I call an api in the TS getProducts() function which returns an observable which is a list of products with attributes of title, artist, price, and image_url. I'm trying to display a list of product titles in my page but I am struggling get the observable to show in the HTML page. Any Help of helpful links would be awesome.

Here is my TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    products;

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {}  

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProducts();
    }
    function
    getProducts() {
        return this.api.get("Products")
          .map((response: Response) => {
            var result = response.json();
            return result;
          });
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML Template:

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<div layout="row">
    <li ngclass="product" *ngFor="let product of products">
        {{product.title | json}}
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return value from `getProducts` is of type Observable and you must treat it as such. Try:

```
<div layout="row">
    <li ngclass="product" *ngFor="let product of getProducts() | asnyc">
        {{product.title | json}}
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your code:

1. Observables only execute if they are subscribed to (in your case you're only calling `map()` - which adds a step to the pipeline, but doesnt actually trigger the observable to execute.
2. You're never assigning a value to `products`.

I havent tested this, but it might look something like:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    products: Product[];

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {}  

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProducts().subscribe(result: Product[] => this.products = result);
    }

    getProducts() {
        return this.api.get("Products")
          .map((response: Response) => {
            var result = response.json();
            return result;
          });
    }
}
```

- I've taken the liberty of applying some typing to your properties (and assumed that your api request is returning a list of `Product` objects - if it isnt, just remove the types or replace them with `any`).